# monitor-cpu script in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
 1  # this script checks average cpu load for last 5 minutes
 2  # since this server has only one core the system will be fully #utilized when average cpu load values reach 1.00.
 3  # This script will send warning alert if value exceedes 0.80 so that action can be taken promptly.
 4  # finally it will display the top 10 users and their processes #with highest cpu utilization.
 5  #!/bin/bash
 6  up=$(uptime | awk '{ print$10 }'| sed 's/,$//')
 7  if($up -gt 0.80];
 8  echo "============================================" >> /tmp/load
 9  ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 >> /tmp/load
10  mail -s "warning alert on QA server , CPU load exceedes the warning threshold" priyank.dewli@qpay.com.qa issuing-alerts@nexxuspg.com < /tmp/load
11  exit
```

```
=======================
 error after executing the script
line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line:

```
if($up -gt 0.80];
```

I think you want

```
if (( $(bc <<< "$up > 0.8") ))
then
    echo ...
    ps ...
    mail ...
fi
```

Comment: bash creates problem when we use floating numbers

Comment: @prk: you're right, I didn't notice it. I updated the answer